# Create a user solely for FTP in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ftp, user-accounts, iis

I was tasked to research and create a manual about installing an FTP server on Windows 7, and everything's fine and all until the specified user part during the creation of an FTP site. I'm told that the FTP user must be a new user. Language barrier sets back my understanding of the issue at hand (Japanese colleagues), and what required of me is **to create a user that can't do anything other than serve as a login credential when connecting to ftp, or just not allow me to log in (remotely or locally) to Windows.** So I was wondering how to do it. I've tried just removing the user from all groups including the Users group, and it works, but I know there must be a better way.
Will removing the user from all groups (including *Users*) present an issue?

TLDR:

I need a way to create a user for FTP access only. User should not be able to log in Windows.

This needs to be done on IIS in Windows 7.

UPDATE:

This [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771990.aspx) about user groups doesn't provide enough information for me. If for example, I used IIS_IUSRS group (as it seems the most likely), what will I be able to do?

Comment: @DavidPostill that question doesn't have concrete answers. I know that IIS uses local users, as I've already done so. What I want to know is if I can make a local user that does nothing other than to be a login credential. Adding or removing groups is one option, but I'm quite not sure which group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **to create a user that can't do anything other than serve as a login credential when connecting to ftp, or just not allow me to log in (remotely or locally) to Windows.** So I was wondering how to do it. I've tried just removing the user from all groups including the Users group, and it works, but I know there must be a better way. Will removing the user from all groups (including Users) present an issue?

So if you're configuring your IIS server to allow Windows OS local users to gain access to the FTP directories, etc. which you define, then here's a way to `DENY LOGON LOCALLY`.

1. Create a new "*local security group*" on the OS, ensure it is tied to the GPO (local or domain policy whichever applies in your case):

   **Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment | Deny Logon Locally**.

   Ensure that all the local users or some nested group they are a member of are members of this group and this should ensure they are DENIED ACCESS from local login to this server OS even though they have the local username and password of the account.

**Accessing the Local Group Policy Editor:** From `RUN` type in `gpedit.msc` and then press `ENTER`.

[image]

**RESOURCE:** https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957048.aspx

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.